# Unity find an InputField by its tag and use it for further programming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to achieve this in Unity 5:

```
InputField inp1 = (InputField)GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Age_InputField");
```

But I get the following error:

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to `UnityEngine.UI.InputField'
```

How can find an InputField using its tag and then use it for further programming, like fetching its text:

```
String tex1= inp1.text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself

Either:

```
InputField inp1 = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Email_InputField").GetComponent<InputField>() as InputField;
```

or:

```
InputField inp1 = (InputField)GameObject.FindWithTag ("Email_InputField").GetComponent<InputField>();
```